# mutate_if or map_if within a purrr loop. If result from safely is not null then do stuff

Tags: r, purrr

Before posting I've made a sincere effort to reproduce data that does not share any sensitive info but I failed there. I'm trying to recreate a data frame where I've previously applied purrr's safely function and I thus have a new column that contains the result.

```
pdata
# A tibble: 104 x 4
   MONETIZATION_WEEK_COHORT data                   cut_off clv_obj         
   <date>                   <list>                   <int> <list>          
 1 2020-03-30               <tibble [214,509 × 8]>       7 <named list [2]>
 2 2020-03-30               <tibble [214,509 × 8]>       8 <named list [2]>
 3 2020-04-06               <tibble [496,626 × 8]>       7 <named list [2]>
 4 2020-04-06               <tibble [496,626 × 8]>       8 <named list [2]>
 5 2020-04-13               <tibble [595,775 × 8]>       7 <named list [2]>
 6 2020-04-13               <tibble [595,775 × 8]>       8 <named list [2]>
 7 2020-04-20               <tibble [548,436 × 8]>       7 <named list [2]>
 8 2020-04-20               <tibble [548,436 × 8]>       8 <named list [2]>
 9 2020-04-27               <tibble [529,507 × 8]>       7 <named list [2]>
10 2020-04-27               <tibble [529,507 × 8]>       8 <named list [2]>
# … with 94 more rows
```

Right before arriving at column clv_obj I had run this line:

```
safeclv <- safely(.f = CLVTools::clvdata) # see https://aosmith.rbind.io/2020/08/31/handling-errors/
pdata <- pdata %>%  mutate(clv_obj = map2(.x = data, .y = cut_off,  ~ safeclv(.x, date.format = 'ymd', time.unit = 'week', estimation.split = .y,
                                                            name.id = 'S', name.date = 'TRANSACTION_DT', name.price = 'AMOUNT')))
```

This safely function returns a list with result and errors. If the iteration was a sucess the result will be a clv object, else result will be null and list value errors will contain the error message. Here's two examples from the above data frame:

A successful iteration:

```
 pdata[1,]$clv_obj
[[1]]
[[1]]$result
CLV Transaction Data 

Call:
.f(data.transactions = ..1, date.format = "ymd", time.unit = "week", 
    estimation.split = ..4, name.id = "S", name.date = "TRANSACTION_DT", 
    name.price = "AMOUNT")
 ... more info here...

[[1]]$error
NULL
```

Here is an example where the iteration failed:

```
pdata[2,]$clv_obj
[[1]]
[[1]]$result
NULL

[[1]]$error
<simpleError: Parameter estimation.split needs to indicate a point at least 2 periods before the last transaction!>
```

I would like map over field clv_obj. Where there's a clvdata object (error is null) then fit a model, else just populate with NA).

Tried:

```
pdata %>%   mutate(models = map(.x = clv_obj, ~ if(.x$error == NULL) {pnbd(clv.data = .x$result)} else {NULL}))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `models`.
x argument is of length zero
ℹ Input `models` is `map(...)`.
```

I'm not sure if what I'm asking is the same as what I should be asking: is there a conventional approach to handling this? I'm guessing it's a pretty common use case?

How can I map over clv_obj and where there's a successful result run `pnbd()` on it else NA?

Comment: You may need the ([kind of hidden](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/as_mapper.html)] `.default` argument in `map()` to set what to return if the result is `NULL`.  Or you could manually return `NA` instead? Also, does the `.x$error == NULL` part work? I would more expect something like `is.null(x$error)` there.

Comment: using `is.null()` did allow me to make progress and run the loop. Would like to leave open though if there's a 'better' way to work with purrs safely and map here